# Oracle NoSQL Error Type mismatch in IN operator. LHS type: INTEGER RHS type: STRING

Tags: oracle-nosql

I would like to do the following query `SELECT * FROM ${TABLE_NAME} where id in $keys[]`
When running using, `ARRAY (JSON)` as in the documentation example

```
let statement = `DECLARE $keys ARRAY(JSON); SELECT * FROM ${TABLE_NAME} where id in $keys[]`;
```

I have the following error

```
LHS type: INTEGER RHS type: STRING
```

How to solve this issue. any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the elements of the array that you are sending are string and not integers. Your ID column seems to be INTEGER.

I've supposed that in your program you have something like that

```
preparedStmt.set( '$keys', ["3","4","5","100"]);
```

So a first solution is to send an array of INTEGER

```
preparedStmt.set( '$keys', [3,4,5,100]);
```

Another solution is just change the type of the variable

```
let statement = `DECLARE $keys ARRAY(INTEGER); SELECT * FROM ${TABLE_NAME} where id in $keys[]`;
```

But if you have non integer values you will have the following error

```
preparedStmt.set( '$keys', ["3","4","5","100","BAD DATA"]);
```

here the error

```
NoSQLArgumentError: [ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT] Failed to create Field Value for variable '$keys': Invalid string for Integer: BAD DATA
```

In this case, I suggest to manage this at client level

```
 preparedStmt.set( '$keys', [3,4,5,"100","BAD DATA"].map(i=>Number(i)).filter( value => !Number.isNaN(value) ) );
```